# Power BI: Incorrect Calculation when using isblank logic

Tags: powerbi

When using this formula:

```
EAC Change = 
var EAC  = SGIE_000020_Stage_Level[EAC]
var EACLM = RELATED(SGIE_000025_Stage_Level_History[EAC])
RETURN
       SWITCH
                (TRUE (),
                      EACLM > 0, EAC - EACLM,
                      EACLM = 0, BLANK(),
                      ISBLANK(EACLM), BLANK()
              )
```

The result is: -0.91

When I use this formula:

```
EAC Change =
     var EAC  = SGIE_000020_Stage_Level[EAC]
     var EACLM = RELATED(SGIE_000025_Stage_Level_History[EAC])
RETURN
     EAC - EACLM
```

The result is: -0.01 (which is correct)

Please can you help me to understand why ISBLANK() is causing the Calculation to change, thanks in advance.

EAC = 54.03
EACPM = 54.04
The result should be: -0.01